# PDO connection object not passing to a class

Tags: php, class, object, pdo

Ok, 2 separate php files, one is the main script, the other is the class. I'm trying to connect to a sql database with PDO. I create the PDO connection in the main script, then pass it to a class in the other script, where queries are made. However, I am getting the following error :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/class.php on line 16
```

My understanding was that PHP could pass references to objects across scripts, but the error says the object does not exist.

Below is the main php script, creates the PDO object and passes to a class to be played with.

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['reference']);

require('class.php');

//connect to database, I know that username and password are not included

$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  die ( 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage() );
}

$objReference = new reference($dbh);
$reference = $objReference->getReference();


$_SESSION['reference'] = $reference;
session_write_close();

?>
```

Below is the class.php file. Receives the object and get data.

```
<?php

class reference 
{

    private $reference;
    private $dbh;

    public function __construct($dbh) {
        $this->dbh=$dbh;
        $this->setReference();
    }

    private function setReference() {
            $refid=$dbh->prepare(" SELECT MAX(id) FROM createX "); 
            $refid->execute();
            $id = $refid->fetchColumn();
            $id=$id+1;
            $this->reference = $id;
    }

    public function getReference() {
         return $this->reference;
    }

}

?>
```

Is there another way to pass PDO objects to classes that I am not aware of? Thanks all.

Comment: See if this helps:     public function __construct(PDO $dbh) {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `$dbh` is an instance variable, in your `setReference` function you should be using the pseudo `$this` to reference it:

```
$refid=$this->dbh->prepare(" SELECT MAX(id) FROM createX ");
```

i.e. use `$this->dbh`.

Comment: but since he is setting $this->dbh=$dbh; in the constructor, should he not be able to call prepare without $this->dbh->prepare ?

Comment: @Maximus2012, no. `$dbh` in that case is undefined.

Comment: got it. Thanks for the clarification. I think I got a bit confused with this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting that error is that your DB connection is failing. It looks like you're forgetting to pass the **password** parameter when you attempt to instantiate the PDO object.

if you temporarily comment out the try / catch block you will get a more detailed error message which will likely prove this to be the case.

When you get your DB connection sorted out, I would do the following:

1. Make a dbconnection class.
2. Make the PDO object a protected member of that class.
3. Have your model classes extend the dbconnection class, thereby giving them access to the db connection.

It's much simple and it's more secure, but first sort out your DB connection issue.